# Controlling actual concurrency with tasks

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, task-parallel-library

There are some scenarios where I would like to be able to control the actual concurrency when using tasks.

A good example for this is when writing a small client for load testing the server side API. In that case I would like to have X concurrent requests at any time.

Now , if I use TPL , I would only be able to set max degree of parallelism , which is not the same.
I thought about using long running tasks, but from what I read that's not recommended:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8304b44f-0480-488c-93a4-ec419327183b/when-should-a-taks-be-considered-longrunning?forum=parallelextensions

Of course I can use threads instead of tasks , but if there is an option to achieve actual concurrency using TPL , I would prefer it.

Comment: There is a lot of confusion here. First, why do you care how about the minimum number of requests that are processed? If your machine is fast enough, you may not have to run as many tasks as you think concurrently. Second, there's nothing that prevents you from specifying the exact number, eg with `Parallel.For` and a specific DOP, eg 10. You don't have to use Task everywhere, it's just a primitive. Finally, the best option for processing streams of messages/requests is the `ActionBlock<T>` from TPL Dataflow. You can specify the number of messages to process concurrently.

Comment: The [ActionBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation shows how to create an ActionBlock with a specific DOP and post messages to it. You can also link multiple blocks into a pipeline (called a mesh)

Comment: Thanks , I don't see what's confusing about the question. I would like to have exact control over concurrency, regardless of how fast my program runs. In a load test you often want to have X concurrent calls at any given time.  Accoding to my tests DOP in Parallel.For also doesn't control the actual concurrency. I will read more about ActionBlock to see if it helps.

Comment: I also don't see how an ActionBlock would help in this scneario. It's probably still built on top of other TPL constructs, and thus uses DOP , which does not guarantee exact control over degree of parallelism. see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228609(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want direct control over the number threads running a specific piece of code you should not use TPL. TPL has optimizations going on under the hood like Task Inlining and Work Stealing. Even if you managed to get the correct number of threads going at the same time, you might not generate the expected amount of load. Especially if the tasks spend most of their time waiting, such as in an http or wcf request.

A semaphore would probably suffice.